# How to limit number of items to get displayed in ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want the display only the first 3 items from a list using `*ngFor`

On my component,

```
formInputs: any = [
{name:'foo'},
{name: 'bar'},
{name: 'buzz},
{name: 'dhsfk'},
{name: 'sadsd'}
]
```

On my template,

```
<div class="form-group label-floating" *ngFor="let input of formInputs">
{{input.name}}
</div>
```

And note that, I want to apply the change only in the template itself not in the component.

Comment: Don't know why slice not mentioned in the [ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) doc..

Comment: I have also provided the documentation link dude. It's an array function. So it's not given in ngFor. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `slice` pipe for that

```
<div class="form-group label-floating" *ngFor="let input of formInputs | slice:0:3">
  {{input.name}}
</div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html

Comment: Thanks :) . . . .. .

Comment: Hi.. I got stuck on angular2 select , pls help.. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129925/angular2-learning . I'm sure it takes 10 sec for you.

Comment: Please just post a proper question with source that contains enough information to diagnose the problem. Sorry, I don't have time to chat.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`slice`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html):

> Creates a new List or String containing a subset (slice) of the elements.

```
array_or_string_expression | slice:start[:end]
```

```
*ngFor="let input of formInputs | slice:0:3"
```

Change your code:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating" *ngFor="let input of formInputs | slice:0:3">
  {{input.name}}
</div>
```